# Maven 3.0.5 - Compilation failure due to `lambda expressions` and `diamond operator`

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

Following two errors are given resulting a compilation failure in IntelliJ 14.1.1.

> 1.lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
>
> 2.diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5

Here is my code where problem occurs

```
CompletableFuture<A> b = new CompletableFuture<>();

b.supplyAsync(() -> {
        A a = null;
        try {
            a = new D().b();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b.complete(a);
        return b;
    }, threadPool);
```

Any suggestion to resolve this problem?
I've already went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342713/error-in-compilation-of-code-with-lambda-expression) question. It has provided solution for Eclipse not for Intellij. This may solve by setting up the source and target. But how to do this on intelliJ.

Comment: @Tunaki thanks for the concern. But that suggestion is not working for me.

Comment: It does work, it is independent of the IDE. Maven uses by default Java 5 and this configuration makes it uses Java 8. Please check that Maven is configured correctly in IntelliJ and that the Maven project is uptodate.

Comment: My problem is which configuration should I change in IntelliJ under Maven. This would be a basic question but it is hard to find this.

Comment: You need to put this in the file `pom.xml` of your project.

Comment: tried but this is given an error saying `invalid content was found starting with element plugin`

Comment: It needs to be under `<build><plugins><plugin>`

Comment: you mean 
`<build><plugins><plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working fine. Once I tried with putting that to `pom.xml` it gave above error. I thought this is IDE depended. That is why I rise separate question. But this is duplicating a question. :)